# Mac terminal, conda --version, 'command not found'

Tags: python, bash, macos, anaconda, conda

I am on a Mac. The terminal window doesn't seem to be able to access my bin or bash folder anymore, I'm not sure.

In the terminal window I am typing `conda --version` to determine which version of Anaconda I have installed but I get the message `-bash: conda: command not found`. - Also when I am in Atom, and am using the Python text editor and I'm trying to create a virtual environment, I type `sudo conda create --name myDjangoEnv django` and I get the same message, `sudo: conda: command not found`.
I used sudo because otherwise it would not let me set up a virtual environment without entering a password.

I think I edited the bash profile when I set up the virtual environment.

The thing is, I was able to do all of this yesterday, when I typed `conda --version` in my terminal I got the version of anaconda I installed, and I was able to update the version of anaconda. And in the python editor in Atom, when I typed `sudo conda create --name myDjangoEnv django` it set up a virtual environment. I was also able to update to the latest version of django.

Additionally, I had a new problem. In Atom I couldn't install a package. if I hit install a package, nothing would happen. Yesterday I was able to install packages. However I restarted Atom and now I am able to install packages, but I'm still having the problem listed above.

Does anyone know what is going on? I'm pretty new to all of this stuff. Should I reinstall Atom, Anaconda, django, and Python? Perhaps, I didn't install it to the right location? Is it easier to run all these programs on windows 10?

- Atom is installed in `/Users/myusername/Downloads`
- django: there's no .app for django so its hard to tell where its installed. Some of the folders for django are installed here:

  `/Users/myusername/newproject/newenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

  or another django folder's location is here:

  `/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bokeh/server`
- python: there are so many python folders, 1 python 3.8 folder's location is:

  `/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/lxml-4.5.2-py38h63b7cb6_0/lib`
- Anaconda: `/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3`
- `echo "$PATH"` produces

  `/Volumes/myExternalDrive/opt/anaconda3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`
- conda is installed in: /Users/myUserName/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/conda-4.8.3-py38_0/info/test/tests/test-recipes/activate_deactivate_package/src/etc –

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221154/discussion-on-question-by-johnharbaugh-mac-terminal-conda-version-command-n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PATH` appears to have an incorrect component. Where you see

```
/Volumes/myExternalDrive/opt/anaconda3/bin
```

you should apparently have

```
/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin
```

At a terminal prompt, you can temporarily fix this with

```
PATH=/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

and at that point, you should be able to run `conda --version` and `python3` in that terminal instance, until you terminate it.

The proper permanent fix is to find the place where this was incorrectly configured, and correct it there; probably your `.bashrc` needs a more thorough cleanup, but that's already far outside the scope of your original question.

(This assumes your home directory is `/Users/myusername`; the command `echo "$HOME"` should confirm this. That's where you'd look for `.bashrc` too.)